# Flagging post cast a close vote from app

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, android-app

When on Stack Overflow (a site where I have question-close permission), there appears to be no option to cast a close vote in the Question Options. I can still flag or cast the vote in the browser as workarounds.
When I flagged the post, the main site told me that I had cast a close vote instead, a mismatch from the UI.

[image]

*Android 4.3*

Comment: I would disagree; according to the linked question, the tools hadn't been implemented. Although I do need to change my question, as clicking Flag had cast a close vote.

Comment: It was already asked before, so this one is duplicate. You don't have to delete it, but answering that other question (i.e. implementing the features) will also answer this one.

Comment: Regarding flag becoming close vote it's by design. (looking for the source)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Ah, gotcha. I verified that silent flag becoming a close vote.